# Просто не хочет применят стиль к блоку, понятий не имею, что происходит

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>123</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_proverka.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div calss='box-1'>text1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
div.box-1  {
    background: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: У Вас опечатка.

Answer (score 1):

`calss='box-1'` `->` `class='box-1'`

```css
div.box-1  {
    background: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>123</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_proverka.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='box-1'>text1</div>
</body>
</html>
```