# Не могу понять тему про родителей, наследие. Киньте источник, где можно узнать по подробней, пожалуйста

Tags: html, css

Вот пример
Если я margin помещаю в div.container, то он не срабатывает. Если я font-size помещаю в div.container он работает. Но, при этом в a.navig работает и фонт сайз и маржин

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <a class='navig' href='#'>Air tickets</a>
        <a class='navig' href='#'>R/w tickets</a>
        <a class='navig' href='#'>Hotels</a>
        <a class='navig' href='#'>Buses</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div.container {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.navig {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Baloo Tamma 2', cursive;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Кстати, box-sizing: border-box здесь тоже не работает

Answer (score 1):

Не все css свойства наследуеммые

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Читайте подробнее в интернете.

Font-size не работает для div.container если вы отдельно задали для a.navig. Свойства потомка важнее

Comment: Благодарю, Michael!

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Можете обозначить мой ответ как верный если я ответил на вопрос

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Не помню точно. Наверника где-то есть какая-то кнопка или иконка

Comment: @tamonsnake Знак "галочка" слева от ответа. Здесь тоже - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170959/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82